# How to Backup and Restore Windows 7 using Acronis TrueImage v10

Tags: windows-7

How can I Backup and Restore Windows 7 using Acronis TrueImage v10 (build 4942)

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the user guides for Acronis products, time to do some reading on how to use your software.

http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/download/docs/

I think version 10 is too old for W7, I suggest version 11 or higher.